# Define Off-Topic Close Reasons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

As we know, currently we don't have precise reason for closing a question as off-topic, but I would like users to suggest precise description for marking a question as off-topic, this will help the users understand better that his question was closed for what reason, and we can add those reasons to ...

[image]

For example, we can have a pre defined close vote reason like

> Questions asking for Political and Scientific reasons are considered
>   as off-topic

Now obviously that's a lousy statement to use as a close reason on the main site as it is not well descriptive and also, not that precise.

So I would like some user inputs over this, but before you draft your off-topic reasons, I would like users to refer questions on meta with the tag [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)

> Note: These reasons won't be accepted unless discussed with higher
>   authority, but feel free to share your off-topic close reasons.

---

**EDIT** (Request Completed):

Here are the currently available Off-topic Close Reasons (as of 11-Jan-2017):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

> **Personal advice** question are considered off-topic here. See : Related [meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/asking-for-help-solutions-to-solve-personal-issues-should-be-considered-off-to)
>   for details.

Answer (score 7):

> **Political question and Scientific explanation questions** are off-topic
>   here. See : [Related meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-questions-and-scientific-questions-will-be-considered-off-topic)
>   for details.

Answer (score 3):

> Any hypothetical question can be marked as off-topic.

For example: What would have happened if Lord Rama had not left Seeta maata after hearing the words of a washerman? 
The answer would mark personal opinions as given in one of the previous answers.

Comment: I do agree with it but i suggest to make it bit better written for usage in live.

Comment: Yes, but what's already happened cannot be changed.

Comment: Nothing is written in stones yet :)

Answer (score 2):

Questions that ask for **shopping recommendations** (e.g buying books from Amazon) are off topic.

Comment: Why? If someone asks for Chandogya Upanishad with Adi Shankara commentary then what is wrong with it? In Stack overflow also, any tool no matter how small, even if it is remotely related to programming is considered on topic.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I'm not talking about [tag:book-recommendation] which is on-topic obviously. I'm talking about shopping recommendation like where can I buy or purchase the book...

Answer (score -4):

> The language used in this question seems to be offensive or hurting public sentiments.

Comment: Unless you define "public sentiment", any point in a religion as vast as Hinduism is bound to hurt somebody. No, I do not recommend this.

Comment: @EmacsUser I understand your point, but I quoted this to avoid any use of abusive/foul language, etc in any regards. I haven't till now seen any such message here yet but as we were framing messages so just thought of on what reason will we close a question if it uses abusive/foul language, etc.

Comment: had you said **abusive** instead of **offensive** language, sure i can see working something out in the context of overall abusive standards common to all SX websites. But you used **offensive**, which is debatable.  And in the context of an aggrieved third party, i.e. **public sentiments**, clearly arbitrary whether it is **abusive** or **offensive**.

Comment: @EmacsUser, I just tried to use better words than using the word 'abusive'. Also, since this site is a religion specific site so writing abusive about Gods, Religion, etc will hurt public sentiments. I just suggested what I think could be helpful. I leave it to mods and community owners to decide whether they want it or not.

Comment: how can it be helpful if you expanded the offended to include third parties? How can it be helpful if the aggrieved can be expanded to include the entire public? How can it be helpful if you expanded harm to include mere sentiment and not any tangible harm? How can it be helpful if you leave it to some arbitrary moderator(s) to decide which writing is abusive?

Comment: @EmacsUer, tell me if someone abuses Gods, religion who will be offened, the person who has made such comments, Gods or the people who believe in that specific God, religion who is reading that comment. Obviously, First person won't be as he is the writer, Second person God also obviously will not complain, its the 3rd party that will be offended and in order to not have a fight and keep the community clean, sometimes it is better to close such queations or ask to modify words

Comment: Religion is something which is very sensitive in these days and is prone to raise communal tensions if proper words are not used. Maybe this will not harm anything tangible when it is written but if tension rises between groups then it leads to fights and communal tensions which will lead to harm in tangible mode also. Charlie Hebdo is the latest example I can think of now, there are many others.

Comment: Define abuse? Define clean? I make a statement in ignorance and you want to escalate it to an offense to an entire population of followers who were never in the discussion in the first place. That's how fatwas get started. That's how cartoons beget wars. That's how you curtail free speech and free exchange of ideas. Your idea has never been helpful at any stage, to anyone, for any reason. It was dangerous at the outset and I want to disabuse the notion that people like you think a community needs cleaning. The last thing we need is closing of questions on a open forum to discover the truths.

Comment: First of all, taking your example, if lets say i have clicked on cIose, the question wont be closed until it has 5 votes. Moreover, my point is about writing better words instead of writing abusive. Freedom of speech doesn't mean people should start abusing each other publicly. With powers comes responsibility. I believe, people should be careful  enough to use better words while conveying their feelings. If 5, 10 or mods, etc whoever are entitled to decide, make a common decision then that should be acceptable to everyone. This is the same thing done in case of other closing reasons too.

Comment: @EmacsUser On meta, feel free to use vote to show what you support and what you don't . Final votes on meta also help in determining the final decision, comments are too temporary.

Answer (score -5):

I suggest the following close reason:

- This question belongs to Buddhism.stackexchange.com

Though there is "This question belongs to another site on Stack Exchange Network". I think having Buddhism religion as a close reason would be more specific as Hinduism and Buddhism are related.

Comment: I was thinking for a migration option, migrate to -> buddhism, christianity, jaduaism, islam but again, if we get comparison question, people may close to migrate..

Comment: @Mr.Alien I agree but if the question is about comparison (mainly with non-related religions) then it should be closed as out of scope as mentioned by [Senshin](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/198/is-comparison-of-a-topic-with-other-religions-on-topic#comment535_198).

Comment: @Mr.Alien for normal user, migration option is only for graduated site

Comment: @Mr_Green What Ankit said - migration options (besides to a site's own meta) only can be added to the close menu by the SE staff, and they only do that for graduated sites. In any case, I do not anticipate [buddhism.se] being a common migration target from this site, given that there is no history of this being an issue (thus far), and most people have a good idea of what is considered Hindu and what is considered Buddhist (the only real gray area I can think of is the person of the Buddha himself).