# How did this answer enter the low-quality review queue?

Tags: support, flagging, post-quality, post-review

SE usually doesn't let anyone flag an answer with high # of upvotes (such as the one below) as 'Very Low Quality' so how did [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21885) enter the review queue?

**N.B.** This discussion is *not* about the specific answer below which is now deleted.

> [image]

Comment: Any flag on an answer except a custom moderator flag will send it to the low quality posts review queue, not only VLQ which is basically a useless flag. The answer was probably flagged NAA. Only a mod can confirm what type of flag was actually cast though.

Comment: If this was flagged NAA, I must have reviewed it within the [15 min. duration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658) after which it enters the mod queue. Also, the only available flags on old posts are: 'spam', 'rude or abusive', NAA and 'mod intervention' (VLQ is missing) @Zanna

Comment: Let it be a Not an Answer or Very Low Quality, the review queue is same. This is why I raised an issue on [flagging unsourced answers](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1674/5212) as Very Low quality and Not an answer. Some answers which are in positive score were also seen in the review queue which means it is flagged as "Not An Answer". That meta is also for questioning the misuse of flagging privileges but I got no reply from the community or moderators.

Comment: Couple of my answers also went to that queue despite having good scores. Other users notified me on each occasion. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64129?m=48601485#48601485 .. So now you know what makes that happen :P @sv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by Zanna in comment, when an answer is flagged as NAA (Not An Answer), it pushes the answer to Low quality review queue so that it is reviewed by privileged users.

> <sup>1</sup> **The "not an answer" flag will trigger the answer to be reviewed by ordinary members of the site via the Low Quality Posts review queue** if the answer has never been to that queue before.

From FAQ: [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/260388)

> It usually pushes an answer to the low-quality queue, where its fate is decided by reviewers. If it stays there for too long, the answer is also shown to diamond moderators in their flag queue. If the flag is considered valid, the post is deleted.

E.g the specific answer you've mentioned was flagged as Not an Answer.

Comment: More than "How do I properly use the "Not an Answer"", [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/357396) is a proper guide how to use a Not an Answer flag.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes but this answer is not purposed for guiding how to use NAA

Comment: How long do ordinary members have to review NAAs before a mod looks at it? Is it still 15 mins? I usually don't see many NAAs in reviews maybe because they all show up as LQ posts.

Comment: @sv. There is not separate queue for NAA review. Answers flagged as NAA are shown at Low Quality Queue. Regarding time, yes, if the NAA flag is not solved within 15 minutes in the review, it [will be shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/260388) to moderator dash board, however we (mods) can review them early if we wish. See the ["ignore time filter" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292878/260388).