# Overcritical downvoting, when the question directly relates to Hinduism and its propagation

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[Networking among pujaaris (priests) of various temples in a region](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/networking-among-pujaaris-priests-of-various-temples-in-a-region)

I asked this question. According to me, this is related to Hinduism, but it is being downvoted.
Is inviting suggestions from other members, not allowed ?
 Could anyone explain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, *avoid asking subjective questions* where …

Your question invites a discussion whether Pujaris should be connected through Social Media. This is up to Pujaris whether or not to be connected or be friends with others in the same profession. We are no one to decide whether a person should be friends with others or not. It is a subjective question and will be based on one's personal choice. It is same like asking whether I should be friends with someone.

Your second question is

> In what ways can this be helpful for propagation of Hinduism **on ground** ?

This is another part where it invites user's opinion. We avoid discussions which are purely opinions.

From the same help center page,

> f your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

That question would be closed as "Primarily Opinion Based". The reason is

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, **but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions**, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

There is a good chance these questions will be downvoted, closed and eventually deleted.

It is known that Pujaris are related to Hinduism. This might make you think that your question is related to Hinduism religion. But as a Q&A site, we have limits on which type of questions we allow on this site and which type of questions we do not allow. There is something "On-topic" and "Off-topic".

> his question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, **within the scope defined in the help center**.

The phrase "Within the scope" is  important here because there are limits to a Q&A site what to allow due to various reasons. See **[What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** , our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and questions tagged with [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

[Asking for advises and suggestions is also off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/5212) because advises will be based on opinions and we do not know what exactly is your position and any random advice can be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such clarity. Sarvabhouma ji.

Answer (score -1):

Only questions related to Hinduism are allowed, that question seems like a suggestion for pujaris.

Comment: The question got downvotes because it was inviting opinions or subjective suggestions.

Comment: That question has been deleted. But to me it seems like a suggestion than a question on some topic which requires clarification about the official stance of Hinduism is. But in my experience pujaris are well connected. They have social network. They know someone, and they'll know someone else who knows someone else in some temple, they are connected like that.