# A Notice About Personalized Advice?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Recently while exploring [**Christianity Stack exchange**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) , I came across a notice mentioning that The site does not offer Personalised Advice and is not a substitute for advice of priest , pastor or other trustworthy person. 

 [image]

As Hinduism SE  site is related to spirituality and religion , many users ask [**personal advice questions**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36590/looking-for-sanskrit-hindi-names)  or seek personalised advice about their problems   on our site also and we either have to close the questions or to inform the OP about that.

My question is what about we at   Hinduism SE displaying a similar message at the top of the page ,so that in future the new users will get informed about this policy and will refrain from asking such questions.

---

**UPDATE:**

What text should we add? Give suggestion/feedback in the answer. I have just now added a recent case of Personal Advice Question. So in my opinion we should sort the issue as soon as possible , by unanimously selecting wording of the notice.

Comment: Good request. But if we look at comments under new questions, users are very eager to give advises to others. Even if the question is closed, comments are posted. We should be strict about advising and prolonging in comments to implement this feature. They should closed ASAP and comment section should be cleaned up. Whee did you see this notice? Above HNQ?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma -Haha , I am actually now jotting down the list of some of the other notices that are required. Like notice about serial voting , (as you said ) notice about unnecessary comments etc. :- D. BTW will you pls. write down an answer stating that such features can be facilitated after consulting CM's and most likely it will be available aft. graduation.

Comment: These features are not related to graduation of the sites. These are independent requests and important for a religious site like ours. CM and Developers will look at good FR and bug reports on per site metas also. If this topic about advice in comments is discussed thoroughly on meta ( using this post or new post) we might have a chance about implementing this feature. We should do our part and leave rest for CMs'.

Comment: We can add a notice like that, but we will need some copy appropriate for this site. Maybe you all can come up with some suggestions in the answers below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been updated as outlined in Mr_Green's [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/12713) and, thanks to Shog9 is now live.

[image: Screenshot of new text for the sidebar. "Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor."]

Comment: Thanks for the implementation! :)

Comment: Yes, Very thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 4):

My opinion is as follows:

> Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information,
>   but is not the place for getting personalized advice. It does not take the place of
>   seeking such advice from your priest, or an accomplished Guru.

Comment: Also Acharya , Pandita , Joytisha etc. are also useful .

Comment: What do you mean by "accomplished Guru"?

Comment: @Mr_Green: One who attained realisation.

Comment: That's debatable and personally opinion based. IMO, better to remove it.

Comment: @Mr_Green: I don't think my opinion will be taken as final word :-).  Let it be there and the moderators may take the final call.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv "moderators may take the final call". Community takes the decision. Moderators are a part of it only.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: Thanks for the information

Answer (score 4):

I believe this would be more fitting -

> Hinduism Stack Exchange is a website for answering queries about Sanatana Dharama. It does not offer [personal advise](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/16030), and is not a substitute for Guru, Pandit, elders and other trustworthy counselors. See the [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478) for more information about what kind of content is acceptable on this site.

Comment: Since our site is an English language based, the words used should also be in English and popular. Astrologer is better than Jyotishi. It's not a constant term for astrologer. I feel it's a bit lengthy. Users will know it's Hinduism site by its name. How many international visitors would know Sanatana Dharma is Hinduism? We should try to keep it simple.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - See the word Rabbi from same notice - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/  Rabbi is not a english word.

Comment: @Swift This notice is lengthy. Since this is only about personalized advice, linking to that meta question would be enough. For English and Sanskrit, Jyotishi is not a correct word for astrologer. Jyotisha, Jyotish and many more words are used in different languages. Guru, pundit, Acharya are used in this notice. I'm only taking about usage of correct and popular words. I think using many words looks redundant to me because many consider Guru = Acharya, Pandit .

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes the list is lengthy. I think trustworthy counselors and Pandiata is all together same.And as you have said either Acharya or Guru , shrinking the list.

Comment: This would be more general statement. First line looks about the introduction which is included in [tour] page, third line is included in the [help]. Since our concern is to avoid personal advice question only second line seems more significant. @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Yeah, that is correct. - " Like any library .... offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice"  this line is common in both Christianity and Judaism notices. I will ask OP to edit the post. Or I will do  it aft. sometime.

Answer (score 3):

What do you guys think of this? I didn't change much as I think most of it applies here as well.

> Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but *does not offer [personalized advice](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/277)*, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor.

Comment: I think counselor is generic term to avoid any such conflicts. We can have "counselor" in last and specific words you mentioned in front like - "priest, guru or other trustworthy counselor"

Comment: Also Acharya , Pandita , Joytisha etc. are also useful .

Comment: The words Acharya, Pundit, Guru are repetitive. Generally Guru = Acharya = Pundit. A priest is better than a trustworthy counseler. Christianity has counselers with Bibilical knowledge. Hinduism doesn't have such people AFAIK. Jyotishi is not a correct word which many know. It is called differently in different languages Why not use astrologer to avoid confusion in Indian languages?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Acharya is usually teacher at PathaShala. Guru can be anyone and pandit means priest or expert. I think Jyotishi term was fine. Astrology is a general term it applies to Chinese and western also. But since we are concerning on Hindu Astrology only, Jyotisha would work.