# Why is asking personalized advice prohibited?

Tags: discussion

Isn't the purpose of HSE to help us learn more about Hinduism? The journey to gain more knowledge is personal for many people, as circumstances and difficulties often push a person to take refuge in religion. I feel allowing personalized questions will really help the community here as well as spread knowledge and awareness, which is the real outcome we all desire.

There is a wealth of knowledge and experience possessed by the members here, that will help so many people from different walks of life.

Yes, perhaps moderation will be required. Just a suggestion, please feel free to delete if you don't agree.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/does-legal-restrictions-apply-to-the-answers-in-our-main-site

Comment: usually u can ask those in chatroom. people also answer a bit in comments. but for formal questions and answers, it must be backed by shastras, otherwise, it's not a religion, just a reality show.

Comment: @hanugm- Thank you

Comment: @mar- Which chatroom? How may I access it?

Comment: @curiousseeker https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism

Answer (score 3):

I'm directly quoting from the Site's Main Message Bar:

> Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other **trustworthy** Counselor.

Further you may read this: [Asking for help / solutions to solve personal issues should be considered off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/asking-for-help-solutions-to-solve-personal-issues-should-be-considered-off-to)

It is important the "personal-advice" part remains off-topic, especially on the Main-Site QnAs because it's 'personal'.

Further, an advice is generally best, when begotten from people you can trust and KNOW properly. This is a virtual realm and more often than not, chances of harm are assured. This becomes more so with a Religious SE (that too as vast as Hinduism), where we don't even have a common and fully-standard set of "rules" for pan-religion, varying as per the relevant sect and belief system. A practice which maybe completely fine and acceptable for one sect, can be totally unacceptable for the other.

Thus, it's best suited that you seek "advice" from your relevant local community members, elders, ācāryas and gurus, and not from this site. This site is best suited for discussions and debates on general QnAs based on canonical texts and authoritative personalities only.