# Does legal restrictions apply to the answers in our main site?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sanathan dharma has a wide variety of scriptures, covering several topics across the spectrum of universe, human life etc.,

Many countries (including India) may have contemporary laws that directly contradicts with the statements in scriptures.

Suppose there is an achara that has been hailed by the scriptures and is considered as absolutely punishable according to the contemporary laws.

In this context, does quoting and sharing opinion on such acharas or other similar things okay? Or does it attract any legal punishments?

Comment: Shastras mention rules for all 4 yugas. Each yuga has a slightly different rule. In Kali Yuga, many people do not follow shastras. Yet even these people have to be regulated so, constitution/judges makes up slightly more lenient laws. But note that there can never be any law that forces one to act against shastras. At worst, there can be laws which don't punish according to shastras. e.g. if law says 'should not have more than 1 wife', shastras don't 'contradict' by saying 'should have more than 1 wife'. it will only say 'CAN have more than 1 wife'. So it's not a contradiction, so it's ok

Comment: same with Sati or child marriage and most other 'social reforms'. Shastras only say it is recommended, not mandatory. There can be cases where there is direct contradiction, but there are also Prayaschittas for that. Any case, just by living in Kali Yuga, we accept its terms and conditions. We are free to leave earth and return at a better Yuga :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as the discussion is scoped as per the Hindu scriptures but not the user's own opinion or speculation, it is all good.

In other words, users should provide valid authentic citations for such discussions. Failing to provide the same can make the answer look vulgar and should be flagged to mods or vote to delete.

I feel it is fine to edit the post to remove the opinion or speculation if part of the answer is properly sourced and is answering the question but the other part has the user's opinions which are unnecessary. If the posting user reverts the changes we should take other actions but not edit it again.