# Are topics on "VAstu ShAstra" considered in the scope of ON topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags

The ancient Indian science of "[VAstu ShAstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vastu_shastra)" deals with the subjects of establishing harmony between "*Panch MahAbhuta*" or the 5 elements of the material nature, such as Agni(fire), Jala(water), Bhumi(soil), VAyu(Air) & Akash(Ether).
To discuss it in detail, it will surely require its own main tag & subtags, due to vastness of the topic.

Is it considered ON topic on this site?

Comment: I think they should be on topic, but if I recollect, people used to ask more astrological questions rather than meaningful ones, also personal questions arise like "recently bought a flat and want to do so and so thing...", questions like these gets too personal and are not valuable to future visitors. I think, that's where we might fail, lets see what community thinks about this.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, can you expand your comment into an answer. Yes, "recently bought a flat ..." will definitely be closed by members as either "opinion based" or "off topic" due to 'persona advice' nature. However, I feel that VAstu alone can spawn lots of question, once the interest arises. e.g. "Why Agni is considered south-east", "Why aged parents room allowed in north east?", "Is vastu compliance considered <80% if the Brahma-sthAna missing?", "Why a girl child should not sleep at the head of VAstu Purusha?". All these questions doesn't appear like how we have been reading in in this SE so far.

Comment: Yes definitely shud be on-topic.Vastu shastra is discussed in Puranas.Apart from that Vastu shastra is a part of Sthapathya Veda..and we have many treatises on them like the **Vastusutra Upanishad,Viswakarma Vastu Shastra,Kasyapa Shilpa Shastra** and many others..

Comment: @iammilind Yeah, I agree, as long as it doesn't veer into personal advice or scientific speculation, Vastu Shastra is absolutely on-topic here.  Creation of a Vastu tag would be good, but I don't think we need subtags for the time being.  If we gets tons of Vastu questions we can create subtags later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visit [What is the mythological origin of Vastu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14927/277) which says:

> Legend behind Vastu is described in Chapter 252 of Matsya Purana. Lord Matsya narrated the story to Vaivasvara Manu.

So, **I think [vastu-shastra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vastu-shastra) questions are on-topic here.**

[Vastu](http://hindupedia.com/en/Vastu) Shashtra also deals with astrology and has also some significance in psychology, art, yoga etc. (for e.g it affects the human mind and thoughts). There are many [Sanskrit treatises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vastu_shastra#Vastu_Shastras_.E2.80.94_Sanskrit_treatises_on_architecture) on Vastu.

[Vishvakarma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvakarman) is believed the expounder of Vastu Shashtra.

And in case if the question topic primarily lean more towards personal advise or scientific explanation, we've already defined [off-topic close reason](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/207/277) to handle them.