# Can we change the "help center" link appearing in off-topic reason to on-topic page?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, status-completed, help-center

**Problem**:

One of our [current off-topic reasons](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/207/2995) reads as:

> This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help).

The problem with the above help text is clicking on the link takes newbie users to the existing *help center* page with so many questions to choose from. They'll get confused as to why their question was closed as off-topic.

**Proposed Solution**:

Let's point users directly to our [on-topic page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In other words, in the above message, "help center" should be changed to read "on-topic page" with the link also updated.

Comment: I would rather say, that we should update help center rather than redirecting users to on-topic page.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Update how? Too many questions on the default help center page...better to take user to on-topic page as that is where the scope for Hinduism.SE is clearly defined.

Comment: How many generic off-topic questions do you get? Can't you just paste in the appropriate help center link?

Comment: @Shog9 Is that a generic close reason i.e., not site-specific? I thought we could change the text and links as we like. I maybe wrong though.

Comment: No, it's one y'all added here. Don't know why. Btw: close reason info: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the link to tools. "Don't know why" - I know why, some Q's appear to be related to Hinduism or what many Hindus do but it's not necessarily related to Hinduism. E.g., 'why do Hindus drive cars on the right side of the road?' (well it's a UK or Indian thing not limited to Hindus). No other close reason fits well for such Q's.

Comment: @Shog9 I've found that for other communities [such](http://i.imgur.com/2ldOX63h.jpg) help center link to **on-topic** page.

Comment: That's why there's "other" though. This reason gets used on about one question a week, so ain't like there's a flood.

Comment: @Shog9 Agree, but better to have a ready-made reason than having to type in the reason every time in 'other' field.

Comment: Problem is, you have a much harder time recognizing when a problem is growing, @sv. If, say, 10 of the 12 questions closed in the past 90 days were about driving in India, you might want specific guidance for that... But you'd have a hard time seeing it.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, may be you misunderstood my question here. I only want the reason changed to: "This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the **help center [on-topic page](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**". I see what you're saying, but I don't think we'll ever want so specific reasons.

Comment: @Pandya Can you write an answer on how this is fixed? Thanks. I still see the link going to help center and not directly to on-topic page.

Comment: @Pandya Ok, but how is this status-completed without a complete fix? I think it gives the wrong impression....Also, when I try to close a question the link still takes to help-center not on-topic page. There maybe 2 issues here: `1)` how it shows on already closed questions `2)` how the link appear in off-topic close reasons when someone attempts to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've updated (replaced) the close reason from:

> This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help).

To:

> This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Now, the notice will link to on-topic page for questions that will be closed as off-topic now onwards.

You'll find changes at close reason:

[image]

Comment: Seems to work now after initial inconsistency.