# Should we have a new tag called 'general-advice' or 'advice?'

Tags: discussion, tags

This question – [How to start reading Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/how-to-start-reading-bhagavad-gita) – sounds like a personal advice question to me however the community has allowed it.

Since we've decided to allow it, how about a new tag – **[advice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice)** or **[general-advice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-advice)** – for such questions so one can easily locate all such questions?

Other questions where we could use this new tag:

> [How to read Hindu Scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15693)
>
> [How to progress spiritually without discrimination?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10803)
>
> [How do I control and slay indriyas (senses)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8828)
>
> [How to get rid of Pitru Dosha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15865)
>
> [How to plan your own spiritual path](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7847)

Comment: No, I think a tag like that will encourage people to post personal advice questions.  I think a tag like practice is good enough for those sorts of things.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan 'practice' seems too generic. All the above questions are clearly asking for some sort of general advice. "that will encourage people to post personal advice questions" - we could tell them general advice Q's are ok but personal ones are not allowed.

Comment: Rather than encouraging such questions, I think it may be preferable to reword the existing questions so that they don't start with "how do I" and are more factual in nature.  The Pitru Dosha question is already in that form; it's just asking what Hindu scripture says about removing Pitru Dosha, it's not asking for advice.

Comment: I am sure that tag will be a blunder and invite crazy opinion based questions.

Comment: Not an answer to your Q but rather an aside. "How to read the bhagavad gita or some other grantha" is not really seeking of personal advice. There are well-defined parayana krama's for scriptures and these must be adhered to lest people suffer adverse effects.

Comment: What about instructions or pointers? I think these type of synonyms lock the context for generic instructions instead of advice.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would *not* be a good idea to introduce [advice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) or [general-advice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-advice) as it may *motivate personal advice questions* which we obviously [don't](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/394/277) want. Why we do avoid personal advice is explained [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/297/277).  You may [visit](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/297/277) related information/guidance at graduated religion site which clears the idea.

Some of the questions you mentioned in question may be suitable (except [How to plan your own spiritual path](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7847/277)) as they're very generic, useful and significant but we should avoid questions that are *blatantly* about advice which is why I think introducing such tags may not be good idea.

And for such questions mentioned in question, I agree [with](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/764/should-we-have-a-new-tag-called-general-advice-or-advice#comment2744_764) Keshav that [practice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) would work good.