# Update the help center page with all off-topic reasons and other changes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, help-center

Recently, [our help center was edited](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/600/5212) to add a banner like thing on its top. Lines for the scope of our site and guidelines about asking and answering were added to guide the users to appropriate help center pages.

But I believe this change will give only a half result because the on-topic is not up to date. All the on-topic and off-topic reasons are not listed in the on-topic page. Adding more and more questions in the banner will take more space on the screen and decrease the probability of reading the main content of help center pages (That is the reason Stack Exchange has reduced the space for the banners recently and made them closable after reading). The main focus should be on the help center.

On-topic and off-topic pages should give a clear idea about what we can ask and what we can't ask on the site. It helps users while asking questions and for the reviewers while closing and reopening questions. I propose following changes.

1. Adding [Should we close questions related to Sanskrit language and grammar as off-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/748/5212) under off-topic questions with a sentence. "Pure Sanskrit language questions are off-topic" or something like that.
2. Adding a line about Ayurveda. It is a general notion among people that Ayurveda is a Hindu science of treating people. [It is on-topic upto some extent](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/5212). So, there should be mention of Ayurveda with a line "Ayurveda is partially accepted here" and a link to the question on meta for better understanding.
3. Stack Exchange help center pages by default use faq from Meta Stack Exchange for better understanding of the articles. Our site also has a great faq (pointed out by Jon Ericson♦ in one of their answers). Why not we also do the same? So, I suggest [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5212) into [How to answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page in a bullet point.
4. All the on-topic and off-topic reasons for our site are given in the same page i.e., " [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" and off-topic page is provided with the default reasons of Stack Exchange. So, there is not much point in putting "[What topic should I avoid asking?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" at the top (implemented on many other sites on the network). The on-topic page should be moved to the top of Asking section. It improves the chances of reading that page.

The above changes will make the users give a clearer idea on what we can ask and what we can't. Moving important pages upwards will improve user interface.

Can this be implemented?

Comment: "....and other changes" part is not specific to our site, it's set universally throughout the network which would be more suitable on MSE. We [can only edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/260388) the on-topic page.

Comment: What are the other changes you are talking about? Changing the order of on-topic pages?

Comment: Sanskrit on/off-topic is most important.

Comment: @Pandya Even if it was posted on Meta.SE, they would immediately close as this question is about only help center of our site. I think you (mods) can add your part and wait for the part which a developer should add. I think moving order of pages and updating on-topic is in your hands.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma No, ordering of pages is not in our hands.

Comment: @Pandya Oh.. I noticed this on many sites including beta sites. On those sites, on-topic page is first and off-topic page is next. Same on [Anime.se] and graduated sites with design. It would be helpful if that order is followed for us also.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The mods can't reorder them but CMs can. It's a matter of changing the pin order. Older sites pinned the topics in a different order than newer ones. But before I was hired I got the CMs to rearrange them on the sites I moderated. I don't think it's complicated but I'm not certain how to do it.

Comment: @Catija I also included a request of updating the on-topic page with updates in our site's scope. (Our scope has changed since the last edit). Yes, Pandya said that moderators can't edit the order of help pages. So, I expect a dev or a CM to edit the page because it's site specific. Moderators have updated the on-topic page once in the past. Keeping that in mind, I have posted this FR. 1 and 2 requests are within the range of site mods and they could have edited it like they did earlier. Only 3 and 4 need higher intervention. If you think that would be helpful, please edit it.

Comment: It's not really my call. We generally dissuade sites from editing those pages from the default because it means all future network-wide updates will be ignored. If you have exactly what you want to say and that gets a good amount of support, we can discuss it then but only changing a single link isn't significant enough to act on.

Answer (score 3):

The scope of Sanskrit language related questions and that of Ayurveda is now clarified at [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page of help center.

Find an update to [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as follows:

> [image]

Coincidentally a meta request [Change the sequence of help center pages for Asking section](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1882/277) has been raised with [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag which is hopefully be considered as per [*featured* Guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345032/260388).

Comment: Can we make it two liners and with minimal words? Something like `Request for Sanskrit translation` and `purely Ayurveda based without reference to Hindu scriptures`. These are just examples supposed to be exact with the concluded meta posts and hyperlinking to the same meta posts.

Comment: @Mr_Green How about [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwJut.png)?

Comment: yeah seems good to me. Thanks

Comment: @Mr_Green Updated :)

Comment: Thanks! there are many other things which we discussed and decided to be off-topic. Wouldn't it be better to list them out there? (Example: cross-religion, website recommendations, etc.. and also [this link somehow](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1131/93) )

Comment: Let's continue discussed on chat-room.