# Change the sequence of help center pages for Asking section

Tags: support, status-completed, help-center

Presently the order of help-center pages (for the section of ["Asking"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/asking)) is as follows:

> - What types of questions should I avoid asking?
> - What does it mean if a question is "closed"?
> - What topics can I ask about here?

We recommend users joining the site to visit the [help-center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help) and I think **new users who are joining site should first of all get aware about scope of the site. So, I suggest to change the sequence as follows**:

> - What topics can I ask about here?
> - What types of questions should I avoid asking?
> - What does it mean if a question is "closed"?
>
> > [image]

In addition to the reason said above, moderators can only change the [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page and *can't change* [dont-ask](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page. So we usually declare the questions which we want to avoid in the on-topic page only. So, the community decided list of off-topic subjects are also at on-topic page rather than dont-ask page. So, I request Stack Exchange to alter the sequence at least for this community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done:

[image: Screenshot of Help Center "Asking" section. "What topics can I ask about here?" is the first item in the list.]